# I'm unable to render items on screen

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

I have decided I need to use redux in my application and have starting to change my app to use redux. I'm having difficulty rendering the list of data to my screen there are no errors showing in the console. I have my store set up and reducer and I'm using models everything seems to working fine. my screen is rendering but the data in my store is not displaying. Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

```
import * as React from "react";
import {
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  FlatList,
  SafeAreaView,
  Dimensions,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Image,
  Text,
} from "react-native";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

import BigButton from "../components/BigButton.js";
import HomeScreenImage from "../components/HomeScreenImage.js";
//import HomeData from "../data/HomeData";
import colors from "../constants/colors.js";

const HomeScreen = (props, navigation) => {
  const exercise = useSelector((state) => state.exercise.homeData);
  return (
    <View style={styles.containerTop}>
      <View>
        <HomeScreenImage style={styles.top} />
        <View style={styles.top}>
          <BigButton title="Beast" />
        </View>
      </View>
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.flatListContainer}>
        <FlatList
          data={exercise}
          keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
          renderItem={(itemData) => (
            <TouchableOpacity
              activeOpacity={0.8}
              style={styles.container}
              onPress={() => {
                {
                  if (itemData.item.id == 1) {
                    props.navigation.push("Body");
                  } else if (itemData.item.id == 2) {
                    props.navigation.push("PreMade");
                  } else if (itemData.item.id == 3) {
                    props.navigation.push("Stats");
                  } else if (itemData.item.id == 4) {
                    props.navigation.push("History");
                  } else if (itemData.item.id == 5) {
                    props.navigation.push("CreateTrack");
                  } else props.navigation.push("TrackList");
                }
              }}
            >
              <View style={styles.cardContainer}>
                <Image style={styles.imageStyle} source={itemData.Item.image} />
                <View style={styles.infoStyle}>
                  <Text style={styles.titleStyle}>{itemData.item.name}</Text>
                  <Text style={styles.bodyTextStyle}>{itemData.item.body}</Text>
                </View>
              </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          )}
        />
      </SafeAreaView>
    </View>
  );
};
```

reducer below

```
import HOMEDATA from "../../data/HomeData";
import CATEGORIES from "../../data/CategoryData";
import EXERCISE from "../../data/ExerciseData";
import MEMBERSHIPDATA from "../../data/MembershipData";

const initialState = {
  homeData: HOMEDATA,
  categories: CATEGORIES,
  exercises: EXERCISE,
  membershipData: MEMBERSHIPDATA,
};

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  return state;
};
```

Comment: Assuming the useSelector if returning an array i don't see anything wrong. Try changing the `keyExtractor` to `keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}` (but I doubt it will fix the problem).
Have you tried using constants value for `exercise` instead of "fetching" from the store?

Comment: Thankyou for the reply. Iv run console.log(store.getState()) in App.js. In the console I'm getting back that: object undefined. I will edit my question to include the reducer to see if it add a little bit more clarity for people to see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. The way the data was exported wasn't working with react-redux. It was fine before but when using the export, with redux it wouldn't import it and let me render it on the screen.

this is how I had it before:

```
import Category from "../models/Category";

export const CATEGORIES = [
  new Category(
    "c1",
    "Chest",
    require("../assets/images/FlatBenchPress.jpg"),
    "Time To Unleash The Beast"
  ),
  new Category(
    "c3",
    "Shoulders",
    require("../assets/images/ShouldersPic.jpg"),
    "5% Human, 95% Beast, 100% Prepared To Destroy My Challenges"
  ),
  new Category(
    "c2",
    "Back",
    require("../assets/images/ChickB.jpg"),
    "The Pain You Feel Today, Will Be The Strenght You Need Tomorrow"
  ),

  new Category(
    "c4",
    "Biceps",
    require("../assets/images/Bicep.jpg"),
    "You Gotta Be A Beast There Is No Other Option"
  ),
  new Category(
    "c5",
    "Triceps",
    require("../assets/images/TriPic.jpg"),
    "Train Strong, Positive And Full Of Beast Mode"
  ),
  new Category(
    "c8",
    "Forearms",
    require("../assets/images/MenuTop.jpg"),
    "A Beast Never Fails"
  ),
  new Category(
    "c6",
    "Abs",
    require("../assets/images/AbsPic.jpg"),
    "There Is Time To Rest But It Is Not That Time Now, Now Is Time For Beast Mode"
  ),
  new Category(
    "c7",
    "Legs",
    require("../assets/images/LegsPic.jpg"),
    "A Real Beast Is Put To The Test On Legs Day, The Beast Never Fails"
  ),

  new Category(
    "c9",
    "Cardio",
    require("../assets/images/CardioPic.jpg"),
    "Sweat Out The Weakness It Is A Poison That Must Be Purged"
  ),
];
```

And this is the solution:

```
import Category from "../models/Category";

const CATEGORIES = [
  new Category(
    "c1",
    "Chest",
    require("../assets/images/FlatBenchPress.jpg"),
    "Time To Unleash The Beast"
  ),
  new Category(
    "c3",
    "Shoulders",
    require("../assets/images/ShouldersPic.jpg"),
    "5% Human, 95% Beast, 100% Prepared To Destroy My Challenges"
  ),
  new Category(
    "c2",
    "Back",
    require("../assets/images/ChickB.jpg"),
    "The Pain You Feel Today, Will Be The Strenght You Need Tomorrow"
  ),

  new Category(
    "c4",
    "Biceps",
    require("../assets/images/Bicep.jpg"),
    "You Gotta Be A Beast There Is No Other Option"
  ),
  new Category(
    "c5",
    "Triceps",
    require("../assets/images/TriPic.jpg"),
    "Train Strong, Positive And Full Of Beast Mode"
  ),
  new Category(
    "c8",
    "Forearms",
    require("../assets/images/MenuTop.jpg"),
    "A Beast Never Fails"
  ),
  new Category(
    "c6",
    "Abs",
    require("../assets/images/AbsPic.jpg"),
    "There Is Time To Rest But It Is Not That Time Now, Now Is Time For Beast Mode"
  ),
  new Category(
    "c7",
    "Legs",
    require("../assets/images/LegsPic.jpg"),
    "A Real Beast Is Put To The Test On Legs Day, The Beast Never Fails"
  ),

  new Category(
    "c9",
    "Cardio",
    require("../assets/images/CardioPic.jpg"),
    "Sweat Out The Weakness It Is A Poison That Must Be Purged"
  ),
];

export default CATEGORIES;
```

I have no idea why this has worked but it does. If anyone knows why it works, then please post it here for everyone thank you.